# scikit-learn SVM with a lot of samples / mini batch possible?

Tags: scikit-learn, svm

According to http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html I read:

"The fit time complexity is more than quadratic with the number of samples which makes it hard to scale to dataset with more than a couple of 10000 samples."

I have currently 350,000 samples and 4,500 classes and this number will grow further to 1-2 million samples and 10k + classes.

My problem is that I am running out of memory. All is working as it should when I use just 200,000 samples with less than 1000 classes.

Is there a way to build-in or use something like minibatches with SVM? I saw there exists MiniBatchKMeans but I dont think its for SVM?

Any input welcome!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the SVM in sklearn support incremental (online) learning?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23056460/does-the-svm-in-sklearn-support-incremental-online-learning)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why does it have 10k+ classes? Sounds like too many classes.

Answer (score 4):

I mentioned this problem in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43801000/4541649) to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23056460/does-the-svm-in-sklearn-support-incremental-online-learning) question.

You can split your large dataset into batches that can be safely consumed by an SVM algorithm, then find support vectors for each batch separately, and then build a resulting SVM model on a dataset consisting of all the support vectors found in all the batches.

Also if there is no need in using kernels in your case, then you can use sklearn's [SGDClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html), which implements stochastic gradient descent. It fits linear SVM by default.