# How to continue training svm and knn in scikit-learn?

Tags: scikit-learn, svm, knn

after training since it cost a lot of time is there a way for me to continue my training and add samples using nusvc() and nearestneighbor() in scikitlearn?

Comment: You can always save your whole classificator using pickle or sklearns tuned [model persistence functions](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html). This allows you loading the whole object back. Of course you can then train again with warm_starting from given weights. It it possible that there are limitations though if the base-estimator is not ready for this (adding new data stuff). One possible example: your new data contains one more target-label. This is problematic.

Comment: what if the number of classes are the same is there an easier way to retrain it with less time?

Comment: Read [this for a start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23056460/does-the-svm-in-sklearn-support-incremental-online-learning).

Answer (score 3):

For the SVM, you might be able to use the [online learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_machine_learning) abilities of the [SGDClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier) class. To do so, you would need to use the [partial_fit()](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.partial_fit) function.

Comment: what about for knearestneighbor()?

Comment: I don't see that particular function in the scikit documentation (link below). It doesn't appear that scikit KNN methods have partial fit. How long would it take to retrain KNN on all data? http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.neighbors

Comment: I was wrong. The LSH KNN class does have partial fit. I'd read scikit's documentation on this function and test it out on your data to see if it works well for you. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.LSHForest.html#sklearn.neighbors.LSHForest

Comment: Thanks, but sir  i got to solve first the memory error in my kmeans() when clustering codewords i got memory error.... for k=10000 i have 6gb ram

Comment: But it runs at k=1000.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not totally sure what the solution for your problem would be at this point. I haven't used this particular function. Good luck!

Comment: can minibatchkmeans().parital_fit accumulate the training of cluster centers?